# MvcHtmlString.Create() me devuelve un punto y coma ";"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

soy nuevo en esto con ASP .Net MVC, tengo el siguiente Helper que debería mostrarme un ícono indicando el tipo de ordenación (Ascendente ó descendente):

```
public static IHtmlString IndicaOrden(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string sortOrden, string campo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrden) || (sortOrden.Trim() != campo && sortOrden.Replace("_desc", "").Trim() != campo))
            return null;

        string icono = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up";
        if (sortOrden.ToLower().Contains("desc"))
        {
            icono = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down";
        }

        var tag = new TagBuilder("span");
        tag.Attributes["class"] = icono;

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

En vez de devolverme una etiqueta HTML "`<span class="glypicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>`" me retorna ";"

Aquí hago la llamada en la vista:

```
<th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Ficha","Index",Request.QueryString.ParametrosURL("sortOrden", (string)ViewBag.FichaSort ) )
            @Html.IndicaOrden(sortActual,"VEH_FICHA");
</th>
```

La verdad no encuentro el problema.

Saludos.

Comment: @PHX255 lo hice y también devuelve lo mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

Te devuelve ese ";" porque ese ya lo tienes al costado del último paréntesis.

El siguiente bloque de código se cumple:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrden) || 
   (sortOrden.Trim() != campo && sortOrden.Replace("_desc", "").Trim() != campo))
            return null;
```

retornando un nulo

Comment: Tienes razón, el problema está en esa validación, gracias @fredyfx

Comment: de nada hermano :D eleva ese cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! Por cierto, revisa este workshop que hice sobre ASP.net MVC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY espero te sea de utilidad :D

Comment: Gracias, lo ando revisando.